# Lifting a group action to a Banach bundle

Tags: reference-request, group-actions, fibre-bundles

I have been searching the literature for results on lifting a group action from the base space of a Banach bundle (Important note: NOT Banach VECTOR bundle). The setting I am interested in weaker than the vector bundle setting, hence the lifting to vector bundles results and obstructions to the question do not seem to be too helpful.
In addition, most results I have seen for topological groups involve some compactness assumption (and neither the group nor the spaces involved in my example are locally compact).

In more detail the setting for the question is as follows:
Recall the definition of a Banach bundle (a variant of Dixmiers definition):

Let $E,T$ be Hausdorff topological space, $p \colon E \rightarrow T$ be continuous, surjective and open. Then the triple $(E,p,T)$ is a Banach bundle if for every $t \in T$, the fibre $E_t = p^{-1}(t)$ is a Banach space and the following holds:

(i) $E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, s \mapsto \lVert s\rVert$ is continuous,

(ii) $+ \colon E_\tau \times E_\tau \rightarrow E$ is continuous

(iii) For each $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ the map $E\rightarrow E, a \mapsto \lambda a$ is continuous,

(iv) if $\tau \in T$ and $\{a_i\}_{i \in I}$ is a net of elements in $E$ such that $\lVert a_i\rVert \rightarrow 0$ and $p(a_i) \rightarrow \tau$ in $T$, then $a_i \rightarrow 0_\tau $ in $E$.

It is well known that a Banach bundle is equivalent to a continuous field of Banach spaces (a la Dixmier, though again this does not seem to be helpful for the question)

I have now a free, transitive group action of a topological group (actually even a vector space) on $T$ and am interested in lifting that to an action on the total space $E$. I should also say that neither of the spaces involved is locally compact. The action is relatively explicit, but before I try by hand to construct something, let me ask:

Are there known lifting results for (special) group actions to Banach bundles?